# Changing name of multiple files with conditions

Tags: python, json, file

I got some episodes of a show downloaded onto my PC, but the titles are mixed up completely so it's hard to find the episode I want and I don't want to refer to the wiki to find out which episode is which

Since there's a too many episodes to individually rename them, I've decided to use python to rename all at once, using a json table to store the correct episodes name to compare and replace them (the episodes all have their season number and episode number so I can use that for the comparison)

Currently, I've got this:

```
import os
import sys
from random import randint as mathRandom
nameDict={}

#nameDict["Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E01"]={"Name":"Ed Touchables / Nagged to Ed"}
nameDict["Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E02"]={"Name":"Pop Goes the Ed / Over Your Ed"}
nameDict["Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E03"]={"Name":"Sir Ed-a-Lot / A Pinch to Grow an Ed"}
nameDict["Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E04"]={"Name":"Dawn of the Eds / Virt-Ed-Go"}
nameDict["Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E05"]={"Name":"Read All About Ed / Quick Shot Ed"}
nameDict["Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E06"]={"Name":"An Ed Too Many / Ed-n-Seek"}
nameDict["Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E07"]={"Name":"Look into My Eds / Tag Yer Ed"}
nameDict["Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E08"]={"Name":"Fool on the Ed / A Boy and His Ed"}
nameDict["Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E09"]={"Name":"It's Way Ed / Laugh Ed Laugh"}
nameDict["Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E10"]={"Name":"A Glass of Warm Ed / Flea-Bitten Ed"}
nameDict["Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E11"]={"Name":"Who, What, Where, Ed! / Keeping Up with the Eds"}
nameDict["Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E12"]={"Name":"Eds-Aggerate / Oath to an Ed"}
nameDict["Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E13"]={"Name":"Button Yer Ed / Avast Ye Eds"}

path = 'C:/Users/badfitz66/Desktop/EdEddnEddy/Episodes'

os.chdir(path)

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    filename_splitext = os.path.splitext(filename)

    newSettings = nameDict[filename_splitext[0]].get("Name")
    if  newSettings is not None :
        if nameDict.get(filename_splitext[0]):
            os.rename(filename, filename + str(newSettings)+'.mkv')
```

I'm trying to change the episodes names that are the first values (eg: Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E04) to the episode number and season + the name of each part (eg: Read All About Ed / Quick Shot Ed)

But when I run, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/badfitz66/Desktop/ah.py", line 33, in <module>
    os.rename(filename, filename + str(newSettings)+'.mkv')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E02.mkv' -> 'Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E02.mkvPop Goes the Ed / Over Your Ed.mkv'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `filename_splitext[0]` and `episode["Name"]` print?

Comment: It's just a debug print to check if there was any difference in the names. They just printed the episode name ( eg: Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E1 )

Comment: @ZeDucktor I didn't clearly understood output!. Suppose episode name is Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E01, then whats the `episode number and season + name` means. Do you want to create directory `Ed.Edd.n.Eddy`, directory inside that `01` and move the file there?

Comment: These are the files http://imgur.com/a/UpWDX i'm trying to rename. I'm trying to add the "Name" value to the end of them and I'm using the episode name to make sure I rename them correctly

Comment: can you tell me what should be the new name of  `Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E02`

Comment: Ed.Edd.n.Eddy.S01E02 Pop Goes the Ed / Over Your Ed

Comment: You can't have `/` in file name, so you need to remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop, episode is a string, not a dict. So you cannot access its elements using string index.
Just replace `episode['Name']` with `episode`, and it renamed all my files.

You can use only 1 loop to get things done

```
import os
import sys

nameDict={}

nameDict["test.1"]={"Name":"LOL1.mkv"}
nameDict["test.2"]={"Name":"LOL2.vcl"}
nameDict["test.3"]={"Name":"LOL3.txt"}
nameDict["test.4"]={"Name":"LOL4.py"}
nameDict["test.5"]={"Name":"LOL5.ss"}
nameDict["test.6"]={"Name":"LOL6.lol"}
nameDict["test.7"]={"Name":"LOL7.po"}

path = 'test'

# Loop over all files and directories
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    # Get the name
    filename_splitext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    # print filename_splitext

    # Check if we have new file name in nameDict
    newSettings = nameDict.get( str(filename_splitext[0]), None) 
    if  newSettings is not None :
        # print newSettings
        # Rename with new filename
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename),os.path.join(path, newSettings['Name']))
```

Comment: I've edited my OP to show a new problem (same premise though), if you could have a look at that and help me fix the new error that'd be great!

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark:

Try `episode.Name` instead of `episode["Name"]`